# Show invariance under linear transformation

Tags: group-theory, linear-transformations, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

A simple question but I'm currently stuck.

Let $\kappa\in\mathcal{R}$, and let $\sigma = \kappa I$ and $\pi$ be real $2\times2$ matrices, where $I$ is the $2\times2$ unit matrix. Define the map $R: (\sigma,\pi)\to(\sigma',\pi')$ by the transformation

$\Phi(\sigma,\pi)\to \Phi(\sigma',\pi') = v\,\Phi(\sigma,\pi)\,u^\dagger$,

where $v, u \in SU(2)$, $\dagger$ means conjugate transpose, and $\Phi(\sigma,\pi)$ stands for any $2\times2$ complex matrix.

Show that $\sigma^2+\pi^2$ is invariant under this transformation. Further show that $R\in SO(4)$.

Here is a screenshot of the problem. My question is on part (b).

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: What does the dagger mean, and what is $\Phi$?

Comment: @avs sorry, updated.

Comment: Still not clear.  What exact complex matrix is $\Phi(\sigma, \pi)$?  The one resulting from multiplying $\pi$ by $\sigma$?  But doesn't that always give a real matrix?

Comment: @avs meant to say it stood for any 2 by 2 complex matrix, i.e. the transformation R is defined for 2 by 2 complex matrices generally.

Comment: How are $\Phi$ and $R$ related?  How is $\Phi$ connected to $\sigma, \pi$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\sigma^2+\pi^2$? You appear to be adding a scalar to a matrix.

Comment: @amd rephrased the language.

Comment: @avs $R$ is a map  defined for $\Phi$, and $\Phi$ is the general form of any linear combination of $\sigma$ and $\pi$.

Comment: You say linear combination of $\sigma$ and $\pi$, but one is a scalar and one is a matrix. Is it a formal linear combination? Can you give a concrete example of everything? It sounds like you're quoting some source. Could you cite that source, and either reproduce the context in full or provide a scan/screenshot?

Comment: @arctictern I've updated the phrasing and $\sigma$ is a 2 by 2 matrix now. I am quoting a problem -- screenshot in short order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so $\underline{\pi}\cdot\underline{\tau}$ means $\pi_1\tau_1+\pi_2\tau_2+\pi_3\tau_3$, where $\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3$ are the Pauli matrices. Then

$$ \Phi(\sigma,\underline{\pi})=\sigma I+ \pi_1i\tau_1+\pi_2i\tau_2+i\pi_3\tau_3$$

$$ = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma+\pi_3i & \pi_2+\pi_1i \\ -\pi_2+\pi_1i & \sigma-\pi_3i  \end{pmatrix}. \tag{$\circ$}$$

Part (a) asks you to verify $\Phi^{\dagger}\Phi=\det\Phi=\sigma^2+\pi_1^2+\pi_2^2+\pi_3^2$.

For part (b), you need to verify that for all $2\times2$ special unitary matrices $u,v\in SU(2)$ and any real scalars $\sigma,\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3$ there exist real scalars $\sigma',\pi_1',\pi_2',\pi_3'$ such that

$$ \Phi(\sigma',\underline{\pi}')=v\Phi(\sigma,\underline{\pi})u^{\dagger}. $$

In other words, that if $\Phi$ is in the form $(\circ)$ then so too is $v\,\Phi\, u^{\dagger}$. For this, it helps to notice that matrices are in the form $(\circ)$ if and only if they're a real scalar multiple of a special unitary matrix (can you see why this is?) It turns out, by the way, that $(\circ)$ is one way of representing quaternions as complex matrices (just as one may represent complex numbers as real matrices); you can model the groups $SO(3)$ and $SO(4)$ (arguably more easily) with quaternions.

And moreover, you need to show that $\det(v\Phi u^{\dagger})=\det\Phi$, which should follow easily from properties of the determinant (how it interacts with matrix multiplication and daggers.)

Comment: Thanks! How do you show "... if and only if they're a real scalar multiple of a s.u. matrix" other than explicit verification?

Comment: The columns are orthogonal - that is, it is of the form $(\begin{smallmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ -\overline{\beta} & \overline{\alpha}\end{smallmatrix})$ - and the determinant is a positive scalar; scaling the matrix to $\Phi/\sqrt{\det \Phi}$ makes its determinant $1$.